# Referencing roundtab cell value that is produced by a siunitx macro (here a rounding macro)

Tags: siunitx, spreadtab

In the following script, I'm trying to reference the value tagged by `round`. But I don't know how to do that. If I place the tag inside as shown, the corresponding `cell` produces the number without rounding as one would expect. Placing it outside produces an error.

```
! Package spreadtab Error: Undefined tag in cell A9..
```

How can I reference the rounded value, please? I want to do a similar thing for the case where I have bolded the rounded value. I've added that in the example. Presumably a solution that works for just the rounded value will work for the bolded rounded value as well.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{spreadtab}
\NewDocumentCommand{\roundtonearestten}{m}
{\tablenum[table-format=6.2, round-mode=places, round-precision=-1]{#1}}
\RequirePackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont[Scale=0.93]{TeX Gyre Schola}
\setmathfont[Scale=0.93]{TeX Gyre Schola Math}

\begin{document}
\begin{spreadtab}{{tabular}{S[table-format=6.2, round-mode=places, round-precision=2, mode=text, detect-weight=true]}}
  tag(foo) 10.343\\
  tag(bar) 11.344\\
  tag(normal) cell(foo)+cell(bar)\\
  N :={cell(normal)}\\
  \bfseries:={cell(foo)+cell(bar) tag(bold)}\\
  B :={cell(bold)}\\
  \roundtonearestten{:={tag(round) cell(foo)+cell(bar)}}\\
  %tag(round) \roundtonearestten{:={cell(foo)+cell(bar)}}\\                                                                         
  \roundtonearestten{\bfseries:={tag(roundbf) cell(foo)+cell(bar)}}\\
  R :={cell(round)}\\
  RB :={cell(roundbf)}\\
\end{spreadtab}
\end{document}
```